# Delete from dataframe if coordinate pair not in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `my_dataframe`:

```
    data    | lat       | lon |   
------------+-----------------+--
  10        | 1.0       | 3.0
  11        | 2.0       | 4.0
  21        | 9.0       | 3.0
```

I also have a list of `accepted_coordinates = [(1.0, 3.0), (2.0, 4.0)]`.
I need to delete all rows from the dataframe where the lat/lon are not in `accepted_coordinates`, so the final answer should be a dataframe that looks like:

```
    data    | lat       | lon |   
------------+-----------------+--
  10        | 1.0       | 3.0
  11        | 2.0       | 4.0
```

I tried some things with `groupby` and `isin` but can't figure out how to do this.

Note: it should delete the row if both the coordinates are in `accepted_coordinates` but in the wrong order. ie, if there were a row with coords `(1.0, 4.0)`

Comment: You commented "Would this also work if both the coordinates are in accepted_coordinates but in the wrong order? ie, from my above example, if there were a row with coords (1.0, 4.0)?" twice. Is that desired functionality?

Comment: Sorry -I updated my question (see 'Note'), hopefully that clears it up

Comment: Ah, well that changes everything!

Comment: i updated my solution. In your program, where to the accepted coordinates come from? Is there a way to avoid the creation of the tuples? It might be worth it for you to share more of your code.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert `accepted_coordinates` to dataframe:

```
acc_coor = pd.DataFrame(accepted_coordinates, columns=['lat', 'lon'])
```

and `merge` with `my_dataframe` :

```
res = my_dataframe.merge(acc_coor, on=['lat', 'lon'], how='inner')

res
   data  lat  lon
0    10  1.0  3.0
1    11  2.0  4.0
```

Comment: Would this also work if both the coordinates are in `accepted_coordinates` but in the wrong order? ie, from my above example, if there were a row with coords `(1.0, 4.0)`?

Comment: That's a nice solution. I believe it would also work, and might be more efficient, if you use a right join.

Comment: Also @P.V. I don’t think it would. Could you test it? I don’t have access to a computer right now.

Comment: @P.V. as @Alexander Cécile said it wouldn't, but you can change the `.merge` line with `my_dataframe[(my_dataframe['lat'].isin(acc_coor['lat'])) & (my_dataframe['lon'].isin(acc_coor['lon']))]`

Answer (score 1):

This solution conforms to the edit in your post.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(10, 1.0, 3.0), (11, 2.0, 4.0), (21, 9.0, 3.0)], columns=['data', 'lat', 'lon'])

valid_lat, valid_lon = zip(*[(1.0, 3.0), (2.0, 4.0)])
valid_lat = set(valid_lat)
valid_lon = set(valid_lon)

df = df[df['lat'].isin(valid_lat) & df['lon'].isin(valid_lon)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in the following way:

```
    def get_lat_lon(row):
        # For creating new column
        return (row['lat'], row['lon'])

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['data', 'lat', 'lon'])

    df['data'] = [10, 12, 15, 20]
    df['lat'] = [1.0, 2.0, 9.0, 12.0]
    df['lon'] = [3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0]

    accepted_coordinates = [(1.0, 3.0), (12.0, 2.0)]

    df['lat_lon'] = df.apply(get_lat_lon, axis=1)
    modified_df = df[df['lat_lon'].isin(accepted_coordinates)].drop(columns=['lat_lon'])
```